# Data transferring between GPUs

Tags: tensorflow

Here is how tensorflow works at multiple GPUs at CIFAR10 model example.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html

1. Place an individual model replica on each GPU.
2. Update model parameters synchronously by waiting for all GPUs to finish processing a batch of data.

As tensorflow tutorials mentioned, all model parameters store on the CPU because of avoiding transferring data to and from GPUs.
There is no data transferring between GPUs when they are running with CIFAR10 model? 
data transferring is happening only between CPUs and GPUs?

Comment: yes------------------------

Comment: I'm not sure direct GPU->GPU transfers are implemented in the current version anyway, even when one GPU op tries to use variable on another GPU, I'm seeing gpu->host following by host->gpu memory transfer

Comment: For the 8 GPU system configuration, where some of the GPUs are on different sockets than the others It makes slow communication between the GPUs because of low-latency QPI between the two CPUs.

These days, hardware vendors try to change their GPU server design which is 8 GPUs under the same CPU(PCIe root complex) to get rid of QPI latency.  good example is Facebook Bigsur.

As you mentioned, If data transferring in tensorflow is only happening between CPUs and GPUs, we don't need that kind of hardwares which has one PCIe root?

Comment: That depends where the data goes. If your GPU is connected to CPU0, but the data is uploaded to NUMA node of CPU-1, then it still has to go through QPI link. But QPI is something like 25 GBps, meanwhile PCI Express is going to be <15 GBps, so on a single GPU->GPU transfer you are going to be bottlenecked on the PCI anyway, not QPI

Comment: In terms of typical design of server for 8GPUs, 4GPUs(GPU0~3) are connected to CPU0 and others(GPU4~7) connected to CPU1. When GPU0 try to send a data to the GPU7, It should be go though QPI link and transfer speed dropped. as my result, there is almost 40% performance drop by p2pbandwidth and NCCL test.